# Why are the decimals absent in fractional number even after type casting from int to double?

Tags: c++

From what I've gathered, assigning a fractional number to a double won't work properly unless either the numerator or the denominator is a floating point number, ( and by "not working properly", I mean that the decimals get cut off, I know that numbers can't be stored as fractions of course). However, I've tried type casting ints to doubles before assigning them to another double variable but it still doesn't work. It's not a big deal since I just had to do a minor work around, but why is this the case?

I added some coding I did while testing.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

double convert(int v) {
    return v;
}

int main() {

    int a = 5;
    int b = 2;

    double n;

    n = convert(a) / convert(b);

    cout << n << endl; // Decimals are stored

    a = static_cast<double> (a);
    b = static_cast<double> (b);

    n = a / b;

    cout << n << endl; // Decimals are cut off

    a = (double) a;
    b = (double) b;

    n = a / b;

    cout << n << endl; << // Decimals are cut off

    double c = a;
    double d = b;

    n = c / d;

    cout << n << endl; // Decimals are stored

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2.5
2
2
2.5
```

Comment: `b = (double) b;` This gets an `int` casts it to `double`... and casts it back again to an `int` because that is the unmodificable type of `b`.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int a = 5;
> a = static_cast<double> (a);
> ```

The first line creates an `int` variable named `a` and puts the value `5` in it. The second line explicitly converts the value of `a` to a `double`, then stores that converted value in `a`. However, `a` has type `int`, so there is an implicit conversion to `int`. That is, the second line is functionally equivalent to:

```
a = static_cast<int> ( static_cast<double> (a) );
```

So by the time you get to the division, you are back to integer arithmetic. To get the conversion to floating point to "stick" through your division, you need to avoid throwing it away. You could either assign the converted value to a new variable, as in

```
double aa = static_cast<double> (a);
```

or do the conversion in the same expression as the division

```
n = static_cast<double>(a) / b;
n = a / static_cast<double>(b);
n = static_cast<double>(a) / static_cast<double>(b);
```

Any of these three alternatives will trigger floating-point division.

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
a / b;
```

is integer division (because both operands are `int`) i.e. the output is an integer, whether the output is then assigned to `double` or anything else is irrelevant in the calculation of the result.

Answer (score 3):

Because of *integer division*.

```
n = a / b;
```

Here `a` and `b` are integers so the result is also an integer, this is a rule of C++, so `5/2 == 2`. The integer `2` then gets converted to a `double` which then prints as `2`.